# Vertices with different properties in GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am new to GraphX and I am trying to create vertices for a graph that have different properties. I have a file with vertices that have Id, Type, SongName and others which have Id, Type, Rank, Year. They are in the same file. Not sure if I have to split them. The I created this Vertex class:

```
class VertexProperty() extends Serializable
case class SongProperty(val vertexType: String, val songName: String) extends VertexProperty
case class BillboardProperty(val vertexType: String, val rank: Int, val year: Int) extends VertexProperty
```

I am trying to implement it here but not too sure how or if I am on the right track. Any help please?

```
val BillboardSong: RDD[(VertexId, VertexProperty)] = sc.textFile(vertexBillboardSong).map {
  line =>
    val row = line.split(",")

    (row(0).toLong, row(2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching on the vertex type from the file. Assuming the two possible types are "song" and "billboard":

```
val BillboardSong: RDD[(VertexId, VertexProperty)] = sc.textFile(vertexBillboardSong).map{ 
  line =>
    val row = line.split(",")
    val id = row(0).toLong
    val vertexType = row(1)

    val prop = vertexType match {
      case "song" => SongProperty(vertexType, row(2))
      case "billboard" => BillboardProperty(vertexType, row(2).toInt, row(3).toInt)
    }
    (id, prop)
}
```

Comment: I am getting a type mismatch as SongProperty requires two strings and I am passing a long (id) and a String (row(2))

Comment: Thank you...no problems from the compiler now. I have this runtime error now java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V - is this a problem with the scala version? I am using 2.12

Comment: @gannina Yes, I believe this is another issue. I added a link to another question of yours that hopefully should help you resolve it.